# Is read after update and then verification of updated data is necessary when dealing with SQLite through PHP or Android?

Tags: php, android, sqlite

Is read after update and then verification of updated data is necessary when dealing with SQLite Through PHP or Android ?

For example,
If the following code returns TRUE, does it mean everything is ok and no verification through read data and comparision with the original data is required?

```
public function updateRecord($C_ID,$C_Data) 
{
    try 
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE C "
        . "SET C_Data = :C_Data "
        . "WHERE C_ID = :C_ID";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':C_ID', $C_ID);
        $stmt->bindValue(':C_Data', $C_Data);

        $stmt->execute();
        return TRUE;
   } 
   catch (\PDOException $e) 
   {
       return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite guarantees [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) principles of which A is **Atomicity** and C is **Consistency**.

**Atomicity** refers to the idea that a write either completely fails and is rolled back or completely succeeds in modifying database (db) state.

**Consistency** refers to the idea that as long as you follow the principles of transactional db writes it is guaranteed to be written (as long as the operation returns success) in such a way that it maintains database "state", i.e. all the relations you defined are satisfied.

> From  [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) - SQLite implements serializable transactions
>   that are atomic, consistent, isolated, and durable, even if the
>   transaction is interrupted by a program crash, 
>   an operating system crash, or a power failure to the computer.

Of course you may end up writing transactions incorrectly so you should implement test cases and handle exceptions for your db writes since data **Consistency** does not guarantee data **Correctness**.

Comment: I don't get "data Consistency does not guarantee data Correctness", if it returns true it means everything is fine and finished and correct, ok?

Comment: Yes if it returns true that means the transaction has modified db state successfuly.Consistency implies that the data has been inserted successfully in your database. Correctness implies the data is correct as per your use case - a contrived example would be- you insert a row data that is incomplete but since you've defined the columns as nullable the database will accept the transaction and insert the row. In that case the db data is consistent but not correct and cannot be relied on. hence you will have to null check the data in your code when you retrieve it

Comment: so if I would be sure that I insert a true and complete data, it is guaranteed that the data will be inserted truly and there is no need for verification?

Comment: yes but you yourself may be inserting incorrect data, you should design the database so it does not insert incorrect data/propagates deletes correctly and handle sqlite exceptions